Use vectorised functions instead of the loops
My function is such that it takes the minimum over the range of dataframe which keeps increasing in length and maximum over the dataframe which reduces in length with each iteration.
The dataframe over which this calculations are to be performed are a subset of another bigger dataframe itself and this results in a nested loop, increasing the time complexity dramatically.
def drawdown(result_df, dict_dfs):
    last_year_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan, index=result_df.index, columns=result_df.columns)

    for idx in range(len(result_df)):
        for stock in result_df.columns:
            past_date_idx = max(0, idx - 250)
            past_date = result_df.index[past_date_idx]
            current_date = result_df.index[idx]

            last_year = dict_dfs['close'].loc[past_date:current_date, stock]

            drawdowns = []
            for i in range(len(last_year)):
                rolling_min = last_year.iloc[:i + 1].min()
                rolling_max = last_year.iloc[i:].max()
                if rolling_min != 0:
                    drawdown = (rolling_max - rolling_min) / rolling_min
                    drawdowns.append(drawdown)

            last_year_df.iloc[idx][stock] = np.median(drawdowns)

    return last_year_df

With this code, is there any function which can help me improve the speed? If yes, then what changes should I make such that the code logic is the same but instead of using loops, I use the vectorised functions!
After comment by @Micheal
def drawdown(result_df, dict_dfs):
    last_year_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan, index=result_df.index, columns=result_df.columns)

    for idx in range(len(result_df)):
        for stock in result_df.columns:
            past_date_idx = max(0, idx - 250)
            past_date = result_df.index[past_date_idx]
            current_date = result_df.index[idx]

            last_year = dict_dfs['close'].loc[past_date:current_date, stock]
            max_dataframe = last_year.iloc[::-1]
            min_dataframe = last_year

            rolling_max = max_dataframe.cummax()
            rolling_min = min_dataframe.cummin()

            drawdown = (rolling_max - rolling_min) / rolling_min

            last_year_df.loc[current_date] = drawdown.iloc[-1]

    return last_year_df

The logic may seem correct at first, but this is not the case with results. My output in both the cases are different. Can someone suggest what is going wrong here?
Below is example from result_df
    ABB IN Equity   ABNL IN Equity
01-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
02-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
03-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
04-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
07-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
08-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
09-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
10-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
11-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
14-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
15-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
16-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
17-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
18-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
21-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
22-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
23-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
24-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
25-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
28-02-2005  FALSE   FALSE
01-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
02-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
03-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
04-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
07-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
08-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
09-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
10-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
11-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
14-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
15-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
16-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
17-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
18-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
21-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
22-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
23-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
24-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
28-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
29-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
30-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
31-03-2005  FALSE   FALSE
01-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
04-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
05-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
06-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
07-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
08-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
11-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
12-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
13-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
15-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
18-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
19-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
20-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
21-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
22-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
25-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
26-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
27-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
28-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
29-04-2005  FALSE   FALSE
02-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
03-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
04-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
05-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
06-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
09-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
10-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
11-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
12-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
13-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
16-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
17-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
18-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
19-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
20-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
23-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
24-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
25-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
26-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
27-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
30-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
31-05-2005  FALSE   FALSE
01-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
02-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
03-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
04-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
06-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
07-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
08-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
09-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
10-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
13-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
14-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
15-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
16-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
17-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
20-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
21-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
22-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
23-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
24-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
27-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
28-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
29-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
30-06-2005  FALSE   FALSE
01-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
04-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
05-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
06-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
07-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
08-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
11-07-2005  TRUE    FALSE
12-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
13-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
14-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
15-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
18-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
19-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
20-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
21-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
22-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
25-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
26-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
27-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
29-07-2005  FALSE   FALSE
01-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
02-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
03-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
04-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
05-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
08-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
09-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
10-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
11-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
12-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
16-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
17-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
18-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
19-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
22-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
23-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
24-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
25-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
26-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
29-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
30-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
31-08-2005  FALSE   FALSE
01-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
02-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
05-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
06-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
08-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
09-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
12-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
13-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
14-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
15-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
16-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
19-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
20-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
21-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
22-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
23-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
26-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
27-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
28-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
29-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
30-09-2005  FALSE   FALSE
03-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
04-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
05-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
06-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
07-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
10-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
11-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
13-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
14-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
17-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
18-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
19-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
20-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
21-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
24-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
25-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
26-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
27-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
28-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
31-10-2005  FALSE   FALSE
01-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
02-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
07-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
08-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
09-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
10-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
11-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
14-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
16-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
17-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
18-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
21-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
22-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
23-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
24-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
25-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
26-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
28-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
29-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
30-11-2005  FALSE   FALSE
01-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
02-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
05-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
06-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
07-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
08-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
09-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
12-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
13-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
14-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
15-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
16-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
19-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
20-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
21-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
22-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
23-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
26-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
27-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
28-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
29-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
30-12-2005  FALSE   FALSE
02-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
03-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
04-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
05-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
06-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
09-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
10-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
12-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
13-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
16-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
17-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
18-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
19-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
20-01-2006  TRUE    FALSE
23-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
24-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
25-01-2006  TRUE    FALSE
27-01-2006  TRUE    FALSE
30-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
31-01-2006  FALSE   FALSE
01-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
02-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
03-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
06-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
07-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
08-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
10-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
13-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
14-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
15-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
16-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
17-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
20-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
21-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
22-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
23-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
24-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
27-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
28-02-2006  FALSE   FALSE
01-03-2006  FALSE   FALSE
02-03-2006  FALSE   FALSE
03-03-2006  FALSE   FALSE

the following is sample from dict_dfs['close']:
    ABB IN Equity   ABNL IN Equity
01-02-2005  177.02  
02-02-2005  180.08  
03-02-2005  184.78  
04-02-2005  191.27  
07-02-2005  195.48  
08-02-2005  207.81  
09-02-2005  223.48  
10-02-2005  222.94  
11-02-2005  222.65  
14-02-2005  228.7   
15-02-2005  225.64  
16-02-2005  225.1   
17-02-2005  222.4   
18-02-2005  223.48  
21-02-2005  223.66  
22-02-2005  219 
23-02-2005  220.96  
24-02-2005  221.5   
25-02-2005  219.7   
28-02-2005  221.5   
01-03-2005  227.8   
02-03-2005  228.26  
03-03-2005  229.79  
04-03-2005  231.58  
07-03-2005  227.1   
08-03-2005  229.44  
09-03-2005  227.82  
10-03-2005  221.5   
11-03-2005  217.92  
14-03-2005  218.8   
15-03-2005  216.46  
16-03-2005  217.28  
17-03-2005  216.46  
18-03-2005  215.2   
21-03-2005  214.34  
22-03-2005  213.4   
23-03-2005  208.93  
24-03-2005  192.69  
28-03-2005  201.7   
29-03-2005  195.39  
30-03-2005  195.59  
31-03-2005  202.35  
01-04-2005  207.09  
04-04-2005  212.14  
05-04-2005  207.81  
06-04-2005  208.89  
07-04-2005  209.79  
08-04-2005  216.1   
11-04-2005  211.78  
12-04-2005  221.5   
13-04-2005  222.58  
15-04-2005  224.2   
18-04-2005  226.9   
19-04-2005  212.72  
20-04-2005  209.81  
21-04-2005  216.1   
22-04-2005  216.64  
25-04-2005  218.26  
26-04-2005  218.82  
27-04-2005  220.35  
28-04-2005  218.98  
29-04-2005  216.11  
02-05-2005  210.7   
03-05-2005  215.56  
04-05-2005  210.71  
05-05-2005  221.52  
06-05-2005  220.7   
09-05-2005  222.4   
10-05-2005  221.5   
11-05-2005  219.7   
12-05-2005  223.3   
13-05-2005  209.81  
16-05-2005  225.1   
17-05-2005  229.26  
18-05-2005  226.01  
19-05-2005  229.62  
20-05-2005  230.86  
23-05-2005  228.96  
24-05-2005  231.4   
25-05-2005  231.94  
26-05-2005  229.78  
27-05-2005  228.7   
30-05-2005  230.86  
31-05-2005  230.86  
01-06-2005  231.05  
02-06-2005  230.5   
03-06-2005  228.97  
04-06-2005  230.5   
06-06-2005  231.4   
07-06-2005  231.08  
08-06-2005  234.11  
09-06-2005  233.75  
10-06-2005  233.25  
13-06-2005  233.21  
14-06-2005  234.49  
15-06-2005  235.02  
16-06-2005  232.12  
17-06-2005  231.13  
20-06-2005  226.9   
21-06-2005  228.89  
22-06-2005  232.33  
23-06-2005  229.6   
24-06-2005  231.42  
27-06-2005  231.42  
28-06-2005  232.68  
29-06-2005  233.57  
30-06-2005  233.21  
01-07-2005  235.28  
04-07-2005  236.83  
05-07-2005  237.2   
06-07-2005  255.72  
07-07-2005  249.51  
08-07-2005  264.72  
11-07-2005  263.1   
12-07-2005  265.8   
13-07-2005  263.28  
14-07-2005  261.35  
15-07-2005  261.3   
18-07-2005  262.92  
19-07-2005  270.12  
20-07-2005  268.59  
21-07-2005  266.52  
22-07-2005  263.1   
25-07-2005  259.52  
26-07-2005  267.96  
27-07-2005  266.97  
29-07-2005  256.08  
01-08-2005  262.92  
02-08-2005  263.14  
03-08-2005  266.88  
04-08-2005  273.22  
05-08-2005  279.13  
08-08-2005  274.98  
09-08-2005  268.32  
10-08-2005  276.44  
11-08-2005  275.54  
12-08-2005  272.16  
16-08-2005  273.9   
17-08-2005  276.08  
18-08-2005  279.32  
19-08-2005  276.42  
22-08-2005  274.62  
23-08-2005  265.8   
24-08-2005  263.82  
25-08-2005  265.62  
26-08-2005  270.12  
29-08-2005  273.72  
30-08-2005  281.11  
31-08-2005  284.53  
01-09-2005  287.23  
02-09-2005  289.03  
05-09-2005  298.95  
06-09-2005  307.94  
08-09-2005  315.16  
09-09-2005  312.98  
12-09-2005  322.75  
13-09-2005  326.86  
14-09-2005  319.64  
15-09-2005  316.94  
16-09-2005  317.49  
19-09-2005  313.34  
20-09-2005  308.32  
21-09-2005  306.44  
22-09-2005  307.13  
23-09-2005  304.72  
26-09-2005  306.32  
27-09-2005  307.95  
28-09-2005  307.98  
29-09-2005  305.24  
30-09-2005  306.32  
03-10-2005  307.04  
04-10-2005  308.84  
05-10-2005  313.88  
06-10-2005  313.34  
07-10-2005  306.14  
10-10-2005  309.74  
11-10-2005  290.83  
13-10-2005  300.05  
14-10-2005  292.63  
17-10-2005  290.11  
18-10-2005  289.75  
19-10-2005  289.64  
20-10-2005  283.09  
21-10-2005  289.57  
24-10-2005  297.04  
25-10-2005  296.23  
26-10-2005  302.76  
27-10-2005  291.73  
28-10-2005  289.95  
31-10-2005  295.35  
01-11-2005  297.37  
02-11-2005  295.35  
07-11-2005  295.33  
08-11-2005  307.94  
09-11-2005  316.62  
10-11-2005  301.64  
11-11-2005  331.35  
14-11-2005  328.65  
16-11-2005  329.59  
17-11-2005  328.7   
18-11-2005  335.31  
21-11-2005  331.39  
22-11-2005  327.78  
23-11-2005  331.35  
24-11-2005  331.89  
25-11-2005  334.05  
26-11-2005  345.04  
28-11-2005  333.14  
29-11-2005  352.96  
30-11-2005  346.94  
01-12-2005  345.04  
02-12-2005  351.16  
05-12-2005  346.66  
06-12-2005  338.55  
07-12-2005  336.39  
08-12-2005  337.29  
09-12-2005  338.55  
12-12-2005  345.77  
13-12-2005  343.06  
14-12-2005  341.43  
15-12-2005  342.15  
16-12-2005  338.55  
19-12-2005  343.24  
20-12-2005  352.89  
21-12-2005  351.34  
22-12-2005  353.86  
23-12-2005  352.06  
26-12-2005  345.23  
27-12-2005  346.84  
28-12-2005  344.86  
29-12-2005  344.14  
30-12-2005  345.76  
02-01-2006  344.14  
03-01-2006  343.96  
04-01-2006  352.08  
05-01-2006  345.77  
06-01-2006  357.46  
09-01-2006  362.86  
10-01-2006  360.18  
12-01-2006  356.56  
13-01-2006  357.46  
16-01-2006  355.66  
17-01-2006  355.86  
18-01-2006  359.26  
19-01-2006  371.87  
20-01-2006  374.75  
23-01-2006  397.98  
24-01-2006  415.99  
25-01-2006  447.5   
27-01-2006  454 
30-01-2006  441.58  
31-01-2006  447.86  
01-02-2006  438.07  
02-02-2006  439.94  
03-02-2006  432.2   
06-02-2006  427.15  
07-02-2006  426.79  
08-02-2006  436.97  
10-02-2006  430.39  
13-02-2006  437.06  
14-02-2006  430.03  
15-02-2006  443 
16-02-2006  441.42  
17-02-2006  432.41  
20-02-2006  424.09  
21-02-2006  430.39  
22-02-2006  432.02  
23-02-2006  428.95  
24-02-2006  432.2   
27-02-2006  443 
28-02-2006  443.9   
01-03-2006  452.94  
02-03-2006  458.85  
03-03-2006  474.87  

I hope this information should suffice and help in getting reproducible results.

For the innermost loop there is cummin and cummax, reversing a dataframe or series can be done with .iloc[::-1].

@MichaelButscher please find the updated question

Can you include some sample input data?

@CodeDifferent please have a look once again, thanks!

Here is the new optimized function. It uses list comprehensions and  vectorizing first indexing calculations. I tested it on 4 rows of your data. Hope it works well on all of your data. However, it can be a starting point to you for more optimization.
def drawdown_vec(result_df, dict_dfs):
    last_year_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan, index=result_df.index, columns=result_df.columns)

    past_dates_idx = np.maximum(0, list(result_df.index - 250))
    past_dates = result_df.index[past_dates_idx]
    current_dates = result_df.index[result_df.index]

    last_years = [
        dict_dfs['close'].loc[past_date:current_date, :] for past_date, current_date in zip(past_dates, current_dates)
    ]
    
    max_dataframes = [
        last_year.iloc[::-1] for last_year in last_years
    ]

    min_dataframes = last_years
    
    rolling_max = [
        max_dataframe.cummax() for max_dataframe in max_dataframes
    ]
    
    rolling_min = [
        max_dataframe.cummin() for max_dataframe in max_dataframes
    ]

    drawdowns = [
        (rolling_max - rolling_min) / rolling_min for rolling_max, rolling_min in zip(max_dataframes, min_dataframes)
    ]

    last_year_df.loc[current_dates] = drawdowns

    return last_year_df

Maybe you can put the last 4 list comprehesions in a for loop. You can compare their performance in ipython using:
%timeit drawdown_vec(result_df, dict_dfs)

